# C++ Timers for a game

Tags: c++, timer

I have been looking into different types of timers that i could use for QueryPerformanceCounter() / QueryPerformanceFrequency(),
after looking into this a bit more i found an example of someone using the timer class...which has a timer that is vanilla...would this be better to use then the windows one (i am trying to keep my code as vanilla as possible) or does it have some massive down side i dont know about?
the tutorial i was talking about is [here](http://www.songho.ca/misc/timer/timer.html)

Comment: The timer you linked does use the Windows functions (when run on Windows). And what do you mean by "vanilla"?

Comment: Try searching on http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Windows High Performance Timer has excellent accuracy and reliability compared to other timers. You won't find better for use in a game. If you want to go on other operating systems, then you can worry about that when the time comes- components like the rendering display system, audio, or even input will all need to be re-written too.

Comment: thanks for the info :D...i was hoping that if there was a multi OS timer it would save me work later if i decide to port it...ahh well looks like i just focus on making it for windows(im using OpenGL and OpenAl so porting them isnt a problem).

Answer (score 0):

The Timer class that you link to is just some random C++ class that this guy made that is basically just a wrapper over QueryPerformanceCounter + etc. It's not particularly good. and also doesn't come with license data. It'd be better for you to just implement the abstraction yourself, since it's simple and then you will understand it when it begins to malfunction.

Answer (score 0):

What would be best is if you implement your own abstract Timer class. Then you can wrap the timing functions for whatever OS you feel like by subclassing Timer, and you won't need to change any other code. I think this is the best option, since it sounds like you are looking for maximum portability.